# Not able to include a header file in qt

Tags: qt

When I give the below statement,

```
#include <QMediaImageViewer>
```

It is showing as QMediaImageViewer: No such file or directory...

How would I include if I need to use QMediaImageViewer?

I am using qtcreator... any way to use this?

Comment: Are you using Qt5? Because if you are, you should know that [it was removed](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/changes.html#removed-features).

Comment: @thuga: so if there any alternate to create a slideshow using Qt 5.2.1  for android devices?

Answer (score 0):

The `QMediaImageViewer` class is part of the "QtMultimediaKit". You have to add this module to your "qmake" file, or add the module in your development environment.

In the qmake file you have to add the module like this:

```
QT += multimedia multimediawidgets
```